# Any way to detect whether the client has downloaded a full picture?

Tags: javascript, dom, events, dom-events

I have implemented a website with a mainly CSS slideshow. The problem is that on my phone with bad internet connection the picture doesn't finish loading and the next picture starts getting loaded, which is bad UX. Is it possible to somehow detect whether the client has finished loading the image via JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `load` event and something near lazyloading to achieve this

```
<img src="mypicture.jpg" onload="pictureLoadCallback(this)">
<img data-src="mypicture2.jpg" onload="pictureLoadCallback(this)">

[...]

<script>
    var pictureLoadCallback = function(el) {
        var next = el.nextElementSibling;
        if(next.tagName === "IMG") {
            next.src = next.getAttribute('data-src');
        }
    }
</script>
```

or use javascript event listener :

```
<img src="mypicture.jpg" class="imgLoad">
<img data-src="mypicture2.jpg" class="imgLoad">

[...]

<script>
    var pictureLoadCallback = function(e) {
        var next = e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
        if(next.tagName === "IMG") {
            next.src = next.getAttribute('data-src');
        }
    }
    document.querySelector('.imgLoad').forEach(function(img){
      img.addEventListener('load', pictureLoadCallback);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does the `onload` method work with `loading="lazy"` though?

Comment: This may need futher research but i think that `loading="lazy"` will start to load every image in current view on browser (it's common lazyload behavior) so on basic slide show, it will load every image that may appear on screen, even hidden by an `overflow: hidden`, so there is a chance that will load 2-3 images at start, at same time (so it will not wait for first image to load) and other image will start to load only when active slide change.

Comment: My current code kind of negates your theory: the images are in the HTML and they are hidden (not overflow, but generally hidden) and it gets loaded up when the property gets changed to visible which even with a decent internet connection somewhy somehow creates a short flashing effect and makes the slideshow not smooth at all... So I have another problem ahead of me as well.